# Bip39 tool - BIP32 Extended Private Key vs BIP32 Root Key

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets

In the bip39 mnemonic tool there is three sections :

1. **Mnemonic** : we input our words or a `BIP39 seed` and the tool compute for us the `BIP32 Root Key`
2. **Derivation Path**: there is a `BIP32 Extended Private/Public Key`
3. **Derived Addresses**

**Questions :**

1- If i want to use Electrum wallet and I have already a wallet. Which key should I have to import ? What is the difference if I import the BIP32 Root Key or if I import the BIP32 Extended Private Key ?

2- Should I use BIP44 instead of BIP32 to import my wallet in an Electrum one ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to import a wallet, you should import a [BIP32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki) extended private key. It is often derived from mnemonics.

> What is the difference if I import the BIP32 Root Key or if I import the BIP32 Extended Private Key ?

The terminology is a bit confusing. The BIP32 derivation is done using a number, called the chaincode, over a private key (called the *master* private key). This private key has nothing special: it's just the starting point of the derivation.
The concatenation of a private key and the chaincode is called an *extended* key.

To import your wallet you need to import the *master extended* private key.

Regarding your question about [BIP44](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki), it is not a replacement to BIP32 just a set of recommendations of *how* to use it.

NB: you might be interested in [the description of the key derivation process](https://developer.bitcoin.org/devguide/wallets.html#hierarchical-deterministic-key-creation) by the bitcoin.org documentation.

Comment: The BIP32 root extended key is derived from the mnemonic not represented by it.

Comment: The 'master private key' and the 'bip32 root key' is the same thing ?